# Does SSHD client has 'CD' command? I need change path after login to run shell scripts, these scripts import others by relative paths

Tags: command, client, cd, sshd

Does SSHD client has 'CD' command? I need change path after login to run shell scripts, these scripts import others by relative paths. But these other scripts cannot be modified because they are a part of the third lib.

it is perfect if SSHD client could change the path after login by 'CD' command.